# React Context Updates Not Firing During OnSubmit Functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the Context API to add user details from a form to a global state. When I submit the form, the state is always "one step behind" - essentially, a double click is required to get the desired result.

Basic recreation of the code (have removed irrelevant bits and some imports):

```
import { UserProvider, UserContext } from "../../StateContext"

export default function SignUp() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext)
  const history = useHistory()

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    user.setName(userDetails.name)
    //logging out the user object here will result in the previous values shown

  }

  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({
    name: null,
    age: null,
  })
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-vertical-batch">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your Name"
              required={true}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setUserDetails({ ...userDetails, name: e.target.value })
              }
            ></Input>

            <FormHelperText>
              Put the name you're best known by online - either a nickname,
              brand name, or your real name.
            </FormHelperText>
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl>
            <TextField
              type="number"
              inputProps={{ min: 18, max: 99 }}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setUserDetails({ ...userDetails, age: e.target.value })
              }
            />
            <FormHelperText>
              You currently must be at least 18 years old to use the platform.
            </FormHelperText>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
 
        </div>

        <input
          id="formButton"
          className="btn sign-up-button"
          type="submit"
          placeholder="Send message"
        />
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

To clarify the issue here - if I submit with a name as "Reikon" and log our the user object, the first time it will return as null, and then the second time it will return "Reikon" as expected.

Comment: the setState function can be viewed as async. my question is why do you want to use the user object immediately after set it?

Comment: it doesn't need to be immediate, I just wanted to check it to see if it worked - I wouldn't actually use it until the user is navigated to the next page, after clicking the signup button

Comment: you can log in your component, you will see it works.

Comment: Yeah it works once the user navigates, so there's no actual issue. Thanks for your help!